# Cannot seem to figure out mistake in Matplotlib Funcanimation syntax

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

Greetings fellow users.

I am trying to do a very simple animation of a vector spinning whose norm is some radius of my choice and has angle theta. The projections on the x and y axes are to be also updated with the rotating vector, but i only get a static image when i Run the Cell

```
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(15,15))


"""
keeping these for later so i don't c/p
theta = angle[30]
vector = np.array([1*np.cos(theta),1*np.sin(theta)])
vectors = np.array([vector, [vector[0], 0], [0, vector[1]]])
origin = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,0,0]])
"""


theta = np.pi/3
radius = 2

def get_vector(theta):
    vector = np.array([radius*np.cos(theta),radius*np.sin(theta)])
    vectors = np.array([vector, [vector[0], 0], [0, vector[1]]])
    return vectors


origin = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,0,0]])
quiver = ax.quiver(*origin, get_vector(theta)[:, 0], get_vector(theta)[:, 1], scale=1, scale_units='xy', angles='xy', color=['red','green','blue'])
ax.set_xlim(-radius-0.5,radius+0.5)
ax.set_ylim(-radius-0.5,radius+0.5)

def update(theta):
    global quiver
    quiver.remove()
    quiver = ax.quiver(*origin, get_vector(theta)[:, 0], get_vector(theta)[:, 1], scale=1, scale_units='xy', angles='xy', color=['red','green','blue'])

    
angle = np.linspace( 0 , 2 * np.pi , 150 ) 
anim = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=angle, interval=50)



x_size = radius * np.cos( angle ) 
y_size = radius * np.sin( angle ) 
ax.plot( x_size, y_size )

plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Here  [The static vector not spinning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cFsA.png)

So i just cannot seem to figure out what am i doing wrong here. My method was to delete the quiver at every frame and just render a new one

Tried to animate a vector and its projections spin. Got a static animation

Comment: Your code runs fine in on my machine. Are you using a notebook of some sort, and if so does the backend that you are using support interactive plotting?